# Laravel's `$request->ip()` doesn't return the last digit of the IP address

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm using Laravel 5, PHP 7, and Homestead, and for some reason when I try to access `$request->ip()` I get back `192.168.10.1`. But in my `/etc/hosts` file I have `192.168.10.10  homestead.test`. Then when I `var_dump($request);` I get the following

```
...
 'HTTP_HOST' => string 'homestead.test' (length=14)
 'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
 'SERVER_NAME' => string 'homestead.test' (length=14)
 'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
 'SERVER_ADDR' => string '192.168.10.10' (length=13)
 ...
 'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '192.168.10.1' (length=12)
```

Has anyone seen this before where the last value gets trimmed from the IP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, `$request->ip()` means `REMOTE_ADDR`, which is the IP(`192.168.10.1`) your browser is using.

`SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_ADDR` is `homestead.test` and `192.168.10.10`, that's your web host's name and your web host's IP.

One of your computer's IP is `192.168.10.1`, your homestead's IP is `192.168.10.10`. So when you access your PHP program, your browser is using `192.168.10.1` to connect to homestead's `192.168.10.10`.

Comment: Ah this makes sense, in which case everything is working properly. Thanks!